# Phrase 'to be shaded'

Tags: lyrics

Recently was listening to the song [Shaded by Fred V & Grafix](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Fred-V-feat-Grafix/Shaded)

What is meant by "Maybe we're shaded"?

Comment: We need more context, shade can be a slang insult, shaded can describe making someones efforts pale in comparison, or shaded could mean 'to hide from view' - amongst many other things.

Comment: Please have a look at the lyrics, it's in the description

Comment: @PatrickBrielmayer You shouldn't make the folks that are trying to help you do the work. Include the lyrics in your question and explain what you've already tried to answer your question (Did you look up "shaded" and none of the definitions fit?) - that will keep folks from wasting your time and their by repeating what you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well literally shaded means unlit, or in the dark.  Though my guess is that the word shaded in this context is suggesting that maybe we're tainted, in the sense that "we", in the context of the song, are not truly good people.

Alternatively it could be suggesting that we'll never be divine or special, literally "shaded" or hidden from plain sight, as in "we'll never be lucky" or "we'll never be special."

As song lyrics typically go, the lyrics are fairly ambiguous, as you wouldn't call anyone "shaded" unless you meant to take their picture and they stood too far away from the light.  So unfortunately, I can't be more specific than this.